# How to store a string that points to a boolean value in a django sqlite database

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models

**What I want to happen:**

I'm building a PTO(paid time off) App in django. I want the user to be able to choose between 4-5 different leave types such as "Jusry Duty", "Voting", "Emergency", etc etc and I want those strings to point to a True or False value that will determine whether or not the leave type is chargeable against the user's total PTO hours.

**The problem:**

The correct True or False value is saved to the database but when I view the record from within the django admin, if it is a True value it ALWAYS shows up as "PTO" and if it is a False value it ALWAYS shows up as "Jury Duty". I believe the reason it behaves like this is because "PTO" is the first True value in the tuple and "Jury Duty" is the first False value in the tuple.

**What I've tried:**

What I have right now is a boolean field on my PtoHistory model that takes in a tuple of LEAVE_CHOICES.

```
class PtoHistory(models.Model):
    LEAVE_CHOICES = (
        (True, 'PTO'), #is chargeable?
        (False, 'Jury Duty'), #is chargeable?
        (False, 'Voting'), #is chargeable?
        (False, 'Military Leave'), #is chargeable?
        (False, 'Bereavement'), #is chargeable?
        (True, 'Emergency'), #is chargeable?
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    leave_start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=False)
    leave_end_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    leave_type = models.BooleanField(choices=LEAVE_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

If I choose "Emergency" and save it, this is how it will look in the django admin.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEgXM.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another field `is_chargeable` and make `leave_type` a `CharField`. Like so:

```
class PtoHistory(models.Model):
    LEAVE_CHOICES = (
        ('pto', 'PTO'), #is chargeable?
        ('jury_duty', 'Jury Duty'), #is chargeable?
        ('voting', 'Voting'), #is chargeable?
        ('military_leave', 'Military Leave'), #is chargeable?
        ('bereavement', 'Bereavement'), #is chargeable?
        ('emergency', 'Emergency'), #is chargeable?
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    leave_start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=False)
    leave_end_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    leave_type = models.CharField(choices=LEAVE_CHOICES, max_length=100)
    is_chargeable = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.leave_type == 'pto' or self.leave_type == 'emergency':
            self.is_chargeable = True
        else:
            self.is_chargeable = False
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

In the `save()` method you can check the value of `leave_type` and if it has a value ('pto' or 'emergency') that is chargeable then `is_chargeable` field should be `True`.

Comment: Thank you Evans Murithi. I was thinking of doing something like this but I wasn't sure exactly how to link the two together to maintain database integrity. I'll let you know how it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, your have some major misunderstandings about the `BooleanField` and `choices`.

First of all, `BooleanField` can only have `True` or `False` value, it cannot take `choices`.

In django, you should have use `CharField` along with `choices`. It won't store what's True and what's False, but record what have you chosen to store on that field:

```
class PtoHistory(models.Model):
    LEAVE_CHOICES = (
        ('pto', 'PTO'), #is chargeable?
        ('jury_duty', 'Jury Duty'), #is chargeable?
        ('voting', 'Voting'), #is chargeable?
        ('military', 'Military Leave'), #is chargeable?
        ('bereavement', 'Bereavement'), #is chargeable?
        ('emergency', 'Emergency'), #is chargeable?
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    leave_start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=False)
    leave_end_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    leave_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=LEAVE_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

So what are the tuples in `LEAVE_CHOICES` mean? The first value is the string that stores in database, the second value is the front end representation in django.

With above fix, you could have a dropdown in admin interface, then you select one of the choices as the `leave_type`.

Please spend some time to read django doc about [model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/), especially [`choices` section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#choices).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Shang Wang. Boolean Fields can accept choices, the choices are just a representation of True or False.